# What's the correct way to report location and spread descriptive stats when you have repeated observations and unequal sampling?

Tags: r, descriptive-statistics

Objective:

Report summary statistics for each treatment x timepoint x condition sub-grouping when there is unequal sampling and repeated observations per subject. It is assumed that all the subjects come from the same population.

I think I want to use this pooled standard deviation formula for spread, but am uncertain:

[image]

A 1% sample of "The Data":

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8), timepoint = c("t1", 
"t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", 
"t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t2", 
"t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", 
"t2", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", 
"t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", 
"t1", "t1", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", 
"t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t2", 
"t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", 
"t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", 
"t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", 
"t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", 
"t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", 
"t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", 
"t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t1", "t1", 
"t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", 
"t1", "t1", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", 
"t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", 
"t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t2", 
"t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", 
"t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", 
"t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", 
"t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t1", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", 
"t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", 
"t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2", "t2"), intervention = c("trt", 
"trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", 
"trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", 
"trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", 
"trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "ctrl", "ctrl", 
"ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", 
"ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", 
"ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", 
"ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "trt", "trt", 
"trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", 
"trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", 
"trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", 
"trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", 
"trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", 
"trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", 
"trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", 
"trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", 
"trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", "trt", 
"trt", "trt", "trt", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", 
"ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", 
"ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", 
"ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", 
"ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", 
"ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", 
"ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", 
"ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", 
"ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", 
"ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", 
"ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", 
"ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", 
"ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", 
"ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl", "ctrl"), condition = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), v_magnitude = c(0.75, 0.096, 0.38, 0.579, 
0.164, 0.175, 0.309, 0.113, 0.293, 0.113, 0.594, 0.112, 0.434, 
0.362, 1.121, 0.458, 0.287, 0.153, 0.258, 0.428, 0.218, 0.644, 
0.254, 0.163, 0.13, 1.102, 0.163, 0.2, 0.348, 0.165, 0.361, 0.064, 
0.481, 0.207, 0.16, 0.225, 0.275, 1.809, 0.366, 0.252, 0.335, 
1.561, 1.173, 0.248, 0.706, 0.206, 0.347, 0.273, 1.57, 0.123, 
0.279, 0.671, 0.11, 0.168, 0.31, 1.291, 0.356, 0.294, 1.902, 
0.192, 0.291, 0.197, 0.543, 1.252, 0.201, 0.152, 0.221, 0.809, 
3.09, 0.313, 0.832, 0.253, 0.648, 0.529, 1.179, 0.224, 0.322, 
1.17, 1.436, 0.35, 0.178, 0.095, 1.657, 0.734, 0.17, 0.312, 0.287, 
0.496, 0.618, 0.468, 0.453, 0.469, 0.364, 0.328, 0.387, 0.54, 
0.279, 0.628, 0.253, 0.323, 0.602, 0.122, 0.323, 0.486, 0.351, 
0.273, 0.751, 0.331, 1.003, 0.824, 2.79, 2.037, 0.637, 0.21, 
0.466, 0.023, 1.133, 0.615, 0.331, 2.305, 0.521, 0.464, 0.355, 
0.343, 0.734, 0.646, 0.263, 0.435, 3.169, 0.118, 0.92, 0.267, 
0.285, 1.798, 0.187, 0.154, 0.92, 0.205, 0.292, 0.45, 0.149, 
2.082, 0.721, 0.528, 0.542, 0.192, 0.083, 0.174, 0.163, 0.33, 
0.281, 0.256, 0.246, 0.409, 0.133, 0.156, 0.183, 0.137, 0.413, 
0.281, 0.727, 0.18, 0.076, 0.11, 0.101, 0.051, 0.225, 0.363, 
0.158, 0.322, 0.298, 0.36, 0.253, 0.336, 0.127, 0.26, 0.167, 
0.353, 0.252, 0.862, 2.506, 0.058, 0.318, 0.284, 0.437, 0.467, 
0.127, 0.982, 3.257, 0.446, 0.154, 0.194, 3.849, 0.891, 0.778, 
0.562, 0.24, 0.328, 0.186, 0.713, 0.274, 0.542, 0.331, 0.82, 
0.364, 0.224, 0.637, 0.228, 0.719, 0.5, 0.598, 0.137, 1.393, 
0.877, 0.325, 0.674, 1.302, 0.221, 0.145, 0.188, 0.248, 2.017, 
1.827, 0.301, 0.155, 0.149, 0.405, 0.7, 0.169, 0.078, 0.598, 
1.302, 0.274, 0.209, 0.602, 0.102, 0.082, 0.134, 0.116, 0.268, 
0.825, 0.297, 0.761, 0.461, 0.657, 0.659, 1.025, 0.666, 0.28, 
0.525, 0.385, 0.598, 0.342, 0.203, 1.588, 1.038, 0.227, 0.186, 
0.492, 0.239, 0.712)), row.names = c(NA, -261L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

8 subjects, 4 per treatment condition. Every subject is measured multiple times at each timepoint and condition.

For the mean, I would usually get the mean per id and then find the mean of that aggregated product. Here's what that routine looks like:

```
df |>
  group_by(id, intervention, timepoint, condition) |>
  summarise(subj_mean = mean(v_magnitude),
           subj_var = var(v_magnitude),
           n = n()) |>
  group_by(intervention, timepoint, condition) |>
  summarise(mean = mean(subj_mean),
           pooled_sd = pooled_sd(subj_var, n))
```

[image]

Where:

```
pooled_sd <- function(var, n, k = n()) sqrt(sum(var * ( n - 1 )) / (sum(n) - k))
```

We ultimately analyze these data with a mixed effects model and perform hypothesis testing on the estimated marginal means.